# Lottery ticket contains 6 numbers, find exactly 4 of the 6 winning numbers, with no repeat.

Tags: probability

Lottery ticked has 6 numbers each from 1-49, with no repeats. Find the probability of matching exactly 4 of the 6 numbers if  the winning numbers are all randomly chosen.

My attempt:

There are ${6 \choose 4}$ ways to match exactly 4.

Each way of winning has the same probability: $ {1\over 49}*{1\over 48}*{1\over 47}*{1\over 46}*{44\over 45}*{43\over 44}$

resulting with: ${6 \choose 4}({1\over 49}*{1\over 48}*{1\over 47}*{1\over 46}*{44\over 45}*{43\over 44})$

I tried a different method, which was correct but I don't understand why this is not a correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability to choose the first  correct number  is $\frac6{49}$. Then you choose the next correct number. The probability is $\frac6{48}$ And so on.

Then the probability of choosing an incorrect number if 4 correct numbers have been choosen is $\frac{49-6}{49-4}=\frac{43}{45}$ Similar for the next incorrect number.

And finally you have to count the ways of choosing 2 incorrect and 4 correct numbers. Here you are right. So finally you have

$$P(X=4)={6\over 49}\cdot {5\over 48}\cdot{4\over 47}\cdot{3\over 46}\cdot{43\over 45}\cdot{42\over 44}\cdot{6 \choose 2}\approx 0.097\%$$

Comment: Thanks! I forgot there were 6/49 the first time.

Comment: Your´re welcome.